# jQuery adding variable content into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating contact form on my website, but i got stuck. I don't know how to put content from variable after each inputs on my website. I can show them into console.log and works perfect but i don't know how to put it on website.

Here's the code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $(".contact_form"),
      fields = $("[data-error]");

    fields.on("click", function() {
      $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
    });

    fields.on("blur", function() {
      var field = $(this);
      field.toggleClass("form_error", $.trim(field.val()) === "");
    });

    form.on("submit", function(e) {
      var hasErrors = false;
      
      fields.each(function(i, elem) {
        var field = $(elem),
          empty = $.trim(field.val()) === "",
          errors = field.data("error");

        console.log(errors);

        // HERE IS ERROR VAR 
        // sth here to put it into html
        
        field.toggleClass("form_error", empty);

        if (empty) {
          hasErrors = true;
        }
      });

      if (!hasErrors) {
        form.submit();
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" accept-charset="utf-8" class="contact_form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Imię" data-error="Podaj imię">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nazwisko" data-error="Podaj nazwisko">
  <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" data-error="Podaj poprawny adres e-mail">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Kontakt" data-error="Podaj poprawny numer telefonu">
  <textarea name="message" class="textarea_field" placeholder="WIADOMOŚĆ" data-error="Wpisz treść wiadomości"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="przycisk">Wyślij</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that presumably you're trying to check that the fields all have a value. If so, you should put the error message generation logic in the `if (empty)` code block.

To actually create the HTML for the messages you can use the `after()` method to insert the error messages after the related `input` element. If you also wrap the errors in an element, such as a `span`, which has a class you can easily use that to `remove()` the elements when the form is submit to be re-evaluated. Try this:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $(".contact_form"),
      fields = $("[data-error]");

    fields.on("click", function() {
      $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
    });

    fields.on("blur", function() {
      var field = $(this);
      var valid = $.trim(field.val()) !== "";
      field.toggleClass("form_error", !valid).next('span.form_error').remove();
      if (!valid)
        field.after('<span class="form_error">' + $(this).data('error') + '</span>'); // add new error messages
    });

    form.on("submit", function(e) {
      var hasErrors = false;
      $('span.form_error').remove(); // Remove any old errors when submitting the form

      fields.each(function(i, elem) {
        var field = $(elem),
          empty = $.trim(field.val()) === "",
          errors = field.data("error");

        if (empty) {
          hasErrors = true;
          field.after('<span class="form_error">' + errors + '</span>'); // add new error messages
          field.toggleClass("form_error", empty);
        }
      });

      if (!hasErrors) {
        form.submit();
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
span.form_error {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" accept-charset="utf-8" class="contact_form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Imię" data-error="Podaj imię">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nazwisko" data-error="Podaj nazwisko">
  <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" data-error="Podaj poprawny adres e-mail">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Kontakt" data-error="Podaj poprawny numer telefonu">
  <textarea name="message" class="textarea_field" placeholder="WIADOMOŚĆ" data-error="Wpisz treść wiadomości"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="przycisk">Wyślij</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It works yeah, but don't work actually how i need it. 
This code works for me like this. I am clicking on input and later on background and shows the error that's good. Later I was writing some information to input, click somewhere else and errors class dissappear but span message didn't hide. I must write text into span and click button to hide error, but i want it to be dynamic like toggleClass before.

Comment: The spans will only hide when you click the submit button again. If you want them to be re-evaluated on `blur()` then you would need to write an event handler for that.

Comment: Actually thats what i am looking for but don't know how to write it :/ 
When i write name and click somewhere else span must hide before click button

Comment: I edited the answer for you. I changed the logic to show/hide the error in the `blur` event handler

Comment: Works perfect, spans are removing now, but class don't toggle like before :/ 
.form_error stays even after send correct message

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad, I flipped the logic on the validation check. Try `field.toggleClass("form_error", !valid);`. I updated the answer

Comment: Really, really Thank You ! :) Works perfect now! :)))

Comment: Yup i did it :)

Comment: Hmmm, i found next problem :/ when u click on input and later somewhere else it shows the error, repeat it couple times and see results :/

Comment: Well found :) I updated the logic of the `blur` handler again for you

Comment: I will check that tomorrow :) thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` for adding string to element or `html()` for adding html code.

Example:

```
var text = 'hello world';
$('div#textHere').text(text);

var htmlCode = "<strong>Hello</strong> World";
$('div#htmlHere').html(htmlCode);
```

Documentation for [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and for [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: But OPs issue seems to be how to create the `#textHere` element dynamically.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh! But *I don't know how to put content from variable after each inputs on my website* could mean 2 things: Add content to existing element *(my solution)* or create a new element in DOM *(yours)*, no? I maybe just missunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get form field values you use `$('#id').val();` the val will get value from form fields. And then you can use `$('#id').html('Enter val here')` that's it.

Answer (score 0):

use can use `text()` or `html()`

Different:

1)If you retrieve text only, u can use `text()`

2)If you retrieve html element with text, then u can use `html()`;

Eg 1 : -

`var text1="hello world";`

`$(".text").text(text1)` ==> hello world

`$(".text").html(text1)` ==> hello world

Eg 2 : -

`var text2="<h1>hello world</h1>";`

`$(".text").text(text2)` ==> '< h1>hello world< /h1>'

`$(".text").html(text2) ==>`

## hello world

`